# Kubernetes StatefulSet For a Micriservice Holding State in Memory

Tags: kubernetes, stateful

I'm in need of some advice on how to deal with a situation where I have a Microservice whose target runtime will be Kubernetes. This service has a database that is the source of truth and has few HTTP endpoints to service the clients. On each of the end-point, I have to check if the clientId is known and this clientId is contained in the database.

I would like to do a few optimizations where I would upon service startup, read the database, fetch all the clientId's, populate that to a local application cache, so that when the request comes, I can look up the in-memory cache and service the request. With this approach, my service becomes Stateful and I would like to know how I could deal with this in Kubernetes. Any thoughs on how I should go about with my usecase?

Comment: Statefulsets are more about dealing with persistent data volumes associated with a service pod, but that's not the case in your design. What kind of trouble are you worried about running into with a deployment in this setup? This does seem like overkill for the data access being described, as primary key lookups even in SQL are often as fast as your network latency.

Comment: I came across the Sidecar pattern. Is this something to explore?

Comment: @joesan I'd reckon you would be the best person to answer that basing on the fact that this is yours architecture. I'd also check `initContainers`.

Comment: @jordanm I'm worried about consistency. I will have 3 replica sets of my pod running at any given time and the contents of the Cache will be updated constantly every 5 seconds. So any one pod not being available for a few seconds might lead to inconsistent cache contents for a while. I would like to avoid this somehow.